# Global structure of submanifolds transverse to fibres of a fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles, submanifold

I try generalising the following "classical" result to the abstract fibre bundle (Rudolph-Schmidt, Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics part I)

[image]

I can state it as follows.

**Global result** Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a fibre bundle and $N$ a submanifold of $E$. Let us assume that $N$ intersects transversally the fibres of $p$ at most once. If $N$ shares the dimension of $B$, then $U=p(N)$ is open in $B$, and $N=s(U)$ for some $s\in \Gamma_U(p)$.

Now, I'm considering what happens if I drop the dimensional assumption on $N$. I conjecture something like that (but I need to figure out how to make it more formal).

**Global result** Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a fibre bundle and $N$ a submanifold of $E$. Let us assume that $N$ intersects transversally the fibres of $p$ at most once. Then, there is a local section $s$ of $p$ such that $N$ contains the image of $s$ as a submanifold.

**Some ideas**
The transversality condition reads for any $a\in N$
$$T_a N+\ker p_a'=T_a E\,.$$
In particular, by the Grassman formula, we have:
$$\dim(T_a N\cap \ker p_a')=\max(\dim N-\dim B,0)\,.$$
If $\dim N=\dim B$, $p_a'$ is an immersion for any $a\in N$. Thus, $p_{\restriction N}$ is an injective immersion. Moreover, $U$ is open for dimensional reasons. Therefore, $p_{\restriction N}$ is a diffeomorphism onto $U$. Its inverse defines the section of $p$ we are looking for.

I cannot replicate the above arguments if $\dim N>\dim B$. Probably, I have to study the distribution $T N\cap \ker p'$.

Would you happen to have any suggestions? Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: When one drops the dimensional assumption on $N$, the result that you state continues to hold locally in the following sense.
Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a surjective submersion and $N\subset E$ be a submanifold. Assume that there exists a point $a\in N$ such that $N$ is transverse at $a$ to the fibers of $p$, i.e. $$T_aE=T_aN+\ker T_ap.$$ (continued)

Comment: Pick an arbitrary vector subspace $V\subseteq T_aN$ such that $T_aE=V\oplus \ker T_ap$. Then there exists a submanifold $M\subset N$ such that $a\in M$ and $T_aM=V$. Hence $T_aE=T_aM\oplus \ker T_ap$. Since transversality is an open condition, up to shrink $M$ around $a$, one can assume that $$T_xE=T_xM\oplus\ker T_xp,\ \text{for all}\ x\in M.$$ (continued)

Comment: Consequently, the restriction $p|_M\colon M\to B$ is a local diffeomorphism. Up to further shrinking $M$ around $a$, one can also assume that the restriction $p|_M\colon M\to B$ is injective. Hence $U:=p(M)$ is an open subset of $B$ and $p\colon E\to M$ induces a diffeomorphism $M\to U$, whose inverse $\sigma\colon U\to E$ is a local section of $p\colon E\to M$ such that $$a\in\sigma(U)=M\subset N.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you expand on why there is a submanifold $M$ of $N$ such that $T_a M=V$?

Comment: That is true in general. Consider a manifold $N$, a point $a\in N$, and a vector subspace $V\subset T_aN$. Then, for any coordinate chart $(U,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ on $N$ centered at $a$, up to relabelling the coordinates, one can always assume that a basis of $V$ is given by $\partial_i|_a+\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_{ij}\partial_j|_a$, with $i=1,\ldots,k$. Then one can take $M\subset U$ as the submanifold determined by $x_j=\sum_{i=1}^kb_{ij}x_i$, for $j=k+1,\ldots,n$. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @agt The example that I have in mind is: $B=\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$, $E=B\times \mathbb R^2$, $p$ is the projection on the first three coordinates, $N=\{(x,y,u,z,t)\in E \mid z=1\}$. For any smooth function $f\colon \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R\mapsto \mathbb R$, $N_f=\{(x,y,u,z,t)\in N\mid t=f(x,y,u)\}$ is a submanifold of $N$ which is the image of a section of $p$.

In this case, I can find a submanifold $M$ of $N$ with the property: $T_aM+\ker p_a'=T_aN$. Maybe this is the case when $p_{\restriction N}$ is a fibre bundle, and there is a "connection" on $p_{\restriction N}$?

Comment: I do not see which role $N_f$ plays in what you just said, could you explain it in more detail?

Apart from this, for the given $N\subset E$, it is true that around each $a\in N$ you can find a submanifold $M\subset M$, with $a\in M$, such that $T_aN=T_aM\oplus\ker T_ap$.

Comment: In your last comment, the submanifold $M$ depends on $a$ (right?). In my example, $N_f$ is suited for any $a\in E$. What conditions are needed to find a submanifold $ M $ of $ N $ such that $T_aM+\ker p_a'=T_aN $ for any $a\in M $?

Comment: Yes, for each $a\in N$ one can find a submanifold $M\subseteq  N$, with $a\in M$, such that $T_aE=T_a M\oplus T_aker p$, but then, shrinking $M$ around $a$, one can also assume that $T_bE=T_bM\oplus\ker T_bp$ for all $b\in M$.

Comment: Perfect, I think you are right. There is not so much difference between my example and the general situation you proposed. Thank you very much!